# viewing commit history in gitblit

Tags: gitblit

I would like to view the commit history for commits related to a specific gitblit ticket.

I created a ticket, associated a branch with the ticket, and did a commit and push to that branch.

I do **not** see the commit in the "activity" tab of the ticket.

I do **not** see the commit in the "commits" tab of the ticket.

I do see the commit in "commits" tab of the repository.

What is a good way to create a ticket in gitblit such that I can associate commits with the ticket?

My goal in doing this is to make it easy to do code reviews on a ticket by ticket basis.

In other words: I want to click on:

1. "My tickets" menu item
2. One of my tickets
3. "Activity" tab
4. and see my commits with subsequent links to see the code differences.

Answer (score 0):

Did you compare the steps you took with the documentation [here](http://gitblit.com/tickets_using.html)?  Have you watched the [screencast](https://vimeo.com/86164723)?

The steps you outlined sound correct.